# whether it is necessary delete item before reduce array length in solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract ArrayOperation {

    string[] public arr;

    function append(string str) public {
        arr.push(str);
    }

    function removeByKey(string key) public {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(arr[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(key))){
                // keep order
                for (uint256 j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j ++){
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                }
                // delete last index
                delete arr[arr.length - 1];
                arr.length --;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function getLen() public view returns(uint256) {
        return arr.length;
    }

    function getArr() public view returns(string[] memory) {
        return arr;
    }

}
```

whether it is necessary to add `delete arr[arr.length - 1];` before reduce array length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

```
delete arr[arr.length - 1];
arr.length--;
```

In **solc 0.4.x**, it is not necessary to do `delete arr[arr.length - 1]` before `arr.length--`.

In **solc 0.5.x**, it is not necessary to do `delete arr[arr.length - 1]` before `arr.length--`, but you may replace both statements with `arr.pop()`.

As of **solc 0.6.x**, it is no longer possible to do `arr.length--`, so you must replace it with `arr.pop()`, which would subsequently make `delete arr[arr.length - 1]` redundant.